# Java Program to calculate Modulo Inverse outputs negative values for numbers greater than 10

Tags: java, modular-arithmetic

```
import java.util.*;  

class ModuloInverse {

    static long mod = 1000000007;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        long num = in.nextLong();
        System.out.println(m_inverse(num, mod));
    }

    static long m_inverse(long a, long p) {
        return m_pow(a, p - 2);
    }

    static long m_pow(long n, long m) {
        long result = 0;

        if (m == 1) {
            return (n % mod);
        }

        if (m % 2 == 0) {
            result = m_pow(n, m / 2);

            return ((result * result) % mod);
        } else {
            result = m_pow(n, (m - 1) / 2);

            return (((n % mod) * (result * result)) % mod);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the java program I wrote to calculate multiplicative Modulo Inverse (modulo 10^9+7). But it gives negative numbers as output for numbers greater than 10.
Can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Just a note: a faster method to calculate the modular inverse is the extended euclidean algorithm. You may also want to have a look at the `BigInteger.modInverse()` method.

Comment: Henry, I'll look into that surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a couple of debugging lines to your `if` statement at the bottom:

```
    if (m % 2 == 0) {
        result = m_pow(n, m / 2);
        System.out.println("m = " + m + ", result = " + result + ", returning " + ((result * result) % mod));
        return ((result * result) % mod);
    } else {
        result = m_pow(n, (m - 1) / 2);
        System.out.println("m = " + m + ", n % mod = " + (n % mod) + ", result = " + result + ", returning " + (((n % mod) * (result * result)) % mod));
        return (((n % mod) * (result * result)) % mod);
    }
```

When I ran this with the value 13, this was the last line printed out:

```
m = 1000000005, n % mod = 13, result = 846153852, returning -428497853
```

Now 846153852 × 846153852 × 13 > 2<sup>63</sup>, so your code is overflowing the range of a Java `long`.

`mod` is 10<sup>9</sup> + 7, and if `result` is between 0 and `mod`, then `result * result` won't be much more than 10<sup>18</sup>, certainly less than 1.1 × 10<sup>18</sup>.  The maximum positive value a `long` can hold is about 9.2 × 10<sup>18</sup>, so once `n` creeps above about 9, there is the chance that `result * result * n` will exceed this value.  As far as I can see, this first happens with `n = 13`.

The product of two numbers modulo `mod` will never exceed the range of a Java `long`, but the product of three or more numbers might do.

One way to fix this is by replacing the line

```
return (((n % mod) * (result * result)) % mod);
```

with

```
return (((n % mod) * ((result * result) % mod) % mod);
```

Comment: Luke Woodward, Man you Rock.

Comment: @SaurabhMehta: which values of `n` were giving you negative results?  I ran your code from 0 to `mod - 1` and told it to print out any negative results.  It printed out nothing.  Your change cannot possibly have made a difference: all you have done is stick an extra pair of parentheses around an already-parenthesised expression, i.e. replaced `(expr)` with `((expr))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
But it gives negative numbers as output for numbers greater than 10
```

That is because youve already reached the `positive overflow` of long thus going back/starts at the negative overflow.

long has this value ranges from `minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of 2^63-1` by the time you reach `2^63-1` it will then go back to `-2^63` and starts from there.

Comment: As far as I understand, the answer can never be greater than 10^9+7. Which is within the range of long. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: The overflow is here `return (((n % mod) * (result * result)) % mod);`